# Support command, control and arrow keys when an external keyboard is attached

Tags: objective-c, ios, keyboard

I have an iOS app where all I want to do is provide more support for basic command key combinations such as command+a, command+s, command+x, command+v and friends when a user has connected a bluetooth keyboard.

I know this is possible. Applications such as Textastic and many other editing apps support these features.

I have looked at UIResponder (which appears to only be used by the pop-up menu), UIKeyInput, UITextInput[Delegate] and other API docs with no reference to how to do this.

It is easy to support which options are displayed in the UIMenuController using (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender. However, this method does not appear to be called when a bluetooth keyboard is attached. So I either need to implement another method specifically for the keyboard or something else.

I now suspect it could be that the text subsystem is responsible for performing the actions. However, there's no documentation that I can find! Also, none of the UITextInput delegate methods are called when an operation is performed. I'm almost thinking the solution is private and that I need to ask Apple specifically on how to get access to these features (which I have just done).

**UPDATE:**

positionFromPosition:inDirection:offset: is the method to use to detect when the arrow key is pressed. After iOS has called this method it then calls setSelectedText:. You'll need to work out the rest of the plumbing.

**UPDATE 2:**

I was able to answer all of the questions I had. Please refer to the marked solution for the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. I had already implemented the UIMenuController methods to support cut, copy and paste. By implementing these features *and* connecting a bluetooth keyboard to a physical device you will automatically get the *basic* command options (a, c, x, v and friends). You need to completely implement UIMenuController UIResponderStandardEditActions. I want to note that in the iOS simulator it will *not* trigger command (a, c, x, v and friends) actions. I was able to observe these features working *only* when a bluetooth keyboard was attached to a physical device -- even though "Simulate Hardware Keyboard" had been enabled in the simulator.

Regarding control/option keys; when you fully implement UITextInput you will also get all of the movement functionality when using arrow keys, arrow keys + control, arrow keys + option, etc. Look at the SimpleTextInput example code file provided by Apple for a better idea on how to implement this.

With that said, you can *not* create your *own* keyboard combinations. Apple asked me to create a ticket for it if I wanted those features, which I don't... I really don't care to support anything more than what they have provided. So, commands like Command+s (save), etc. are not currently possible.

A fun little story for you; Apple said that what I wanted to do was not possible (using command+c, command+v, etc.) with the API. I guess that shows how you helpful their technical expertise is. *Very* disappointing.

**Update:**

Since iOS 7, Apple has made it trivial to capture any key command, esc, etc. Here is an example of how one could capture a variety of different keys:

```
return @[[UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:UIKeyInputEscape modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(escapeKeyPressed:)],
         [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"f" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierCommand action:@selector(commandFindPressed:)],
         [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"s" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierCommand action:@selector(commandSavePressed:)],
         [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"b" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierControl action:@selector(controlBKeyPressed:)],
         [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"f" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierControl action:@selector(controlFKeyPressed:)],
         [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"r" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierControl action:@selector(controlRKeyPressed:)]
         ];
...

- (void)commandSavePressed:(UIKeyCommand *)keyCommand
{
    [self saveFile];
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing "Simulate Hardware Keyboard" just stops the on-screen keyboard from appearing; I'd certainly expect the simulator keyboard shortcuts to continue to work. The "it's not possible" response is probably because the feature is user-facing (i.e. users would expect it to work) instead of developer-facing (there's no API for it).

Comment: I probably also asked the question in the wrong way. It can be difficult to describe what I'm trying to do when I have no idea how the internals work or what is "expected" end-user behavior. The API also does not describe the side-effects of how a particular API will use the data you are providing their system with. For instance, I had no idea that UIMenController was also used to provide short-cut key functionality.I may have just too high of an expectation when it comes to Apple's response. I thought I was clear, but maybe they did believe I was referring to something else.

Comment: The person you asked probably didn't know the feature existed. I suspect a UX tester said "Hey, why doesn't copy and paste on a hardware keyboard work?" and then a developer said "I know! We can hook it into the UIMenuController callbacks".

Comment: @echamber, I need to add similar functionality to my custom view - it needs to respond to certain keyboard shortcuts (cut, paste etc), and to cursor keys. I got the former working based on your answer above (implement UIResponderStandardEditActions) - Thank you!! However, my view is not responding to cursor keys being pressed. I have implemented UITextInput and all of its methods with essentially dummy code, but these methods e.g. positionFromPosition:inDirection:offset do not called (All I have is logging inside this method, no real code). Any pointers?

Comment: @R.S I can't actually remember all of the requirements. I would first make sure that your methods are being called -- by putting NSLog statements in each of the methods. If they are not, make sure that your class interface defines that it is implementing the protocol. interface MyView : UIView <UITextInput>. Also, return TRUE in the (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
method. I believe you may also need to set the MyView class as a delegate to an instance of a UITextInputStringTokenizer. Definitely look at the SimpleTextInput example provided by Apple. I think that will help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method of doing this with public APIs unfortunately. I use a wireless keyboard with my ipad for example, so I've looked into this before. You could, however, implement a workaround if you dont mind using the option key instead of the command key.

Assuming that youre making a text editor type of an application, you could do this: poll each character as it is typed and compare it against certain "special function characters" using a switch statement. When a user types a key when option is held down, special characters (such as “, », ü, etc) are inserted. Just find the unicode values of these characters and perform a soecific action when one of these keys is pressed. Also, notice how holding shift in addition to the option key outputs a different character.

Comment: Thank you so much for this info! I'll see what I can whip up.

Comment: Yup. The option key works. I'll use that key for now. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem. I remember using an app (I think it was Textastic, best code editor btw) that stated that it couldn't implement keyboard shortcuts, but this made me think about the problem, and this solution is the one that I thought up. Would be interesting to see a third-party library that made convenience functions for this.

Comment: I am unmarking this as the solution. I _know_ there is a way to support the basic command+s, command+c and friends. I _believe_ UIResponder is the class I need to use but it is not working. I'm going to update the main question to be more clear.

Comment: It *cannot* be done in iOS without resorting to using private APIs. The system won't let you read keys directly from the keyboard. I'm sorry, but this is intended behavior.

Comment: Only some of my requests are not intended behavior (command+s, etc.). I now have what I want working. Please review my response below. Also, I never asked to read the raw keys from the keyboard. Maybe I should have been more clear about that. I simply wanted to support the existing features which I _knew_ existed but weren't working for some reason.

Comment: And then the user picks a different keyboard layout and your lookup table stops working...

Comment: Yes. This is another concern I had. I still like the idea of extending the option keys as @C0deH4cker has pointed out. I don't know well it would translate to different keyboard layouts though. If I ever do end up supporting the option key I may to provide the option key only for en-US keyboards initially. I'm not sure I want to take on that challenge yet.