# How to capture keyboard events iOS / Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am struggling with identifying the key events in my iPhone application.

I want to assign shift, control, command, alt keys to my customize UIButton which is created in a view with the same functionality (shift, alt, control, etc).

Can any one have an idea how to come out this problem?

I am not trying for Mac OS. For iOS I am trying.

Comment: Please see this answer I posted earlier:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11201255/1344461 It discusses the limitations of the wireless keyboard on iOS and a method of how to work around these obstacles.

Comment: For that,You need to reconstruct the whole framework..You cannot override the methods which have written by apple for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use 'shift' key (represent the up arrow) in iOS keyboard but not the remaining.